# Email: legitimate duplicate email header keys with mutually exclusive values

Tags: email, email-headers

In email the `Received:` header can legitimately occur more than once with mutually exclusive values...

> Received: three.example.com
>
> Received: two.example.com
>
> Received: one.example.com

Are there any other headers can occur in email headers multiple times legitimately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ya there are other headers that can appear more than once and is clearly explained here in RFC [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6)

Headers that can appear more than once

- comments
- keywords
- optional-field
- trace
- resent-date
- resent-from
- resent-sender
- resent-to
- resent-cc
- resent-bcc
- resent-msg-id

Check the link above for more clarity.

Comment: Note that "optional-field" is basically any field not defined in that particular RFC.